# Custom Notification Sound FireBase

Tags: firebase, xamarin.android

How I can send a notification to xamarin.android project to make the phone ring like calling I tried to create raw folder inside Resource and set my ringtone their but unfortunately it's not working

is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a raw folder in Resource and put the mp3 file in it with `AndroidResource` Build Action.

Set the custom sound of Notification channels would cover the default sound.

You could use the custtom Notification via `SetSound` of channel.

The Whole of creating channel:

```
  void CreateNotificationChannel1()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification 
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }
        var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
               .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
               .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

        var path = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("android.resource://com.companyname.NotificationChannelsDemo/" + Resource.Raw.Hello);
        var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.channel_name);
        var description = GetString(Resource.String.channel_description);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID1, name, NotificationImportance.Max)
        {
            Description = description
        };
        channel.SetSound(path, alarmAttributes);
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

For more information about how to use channel of notification, you could check the link below. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough